# how to resolve error 17836, Severity: 20, State: 14?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Length specified in network packet payload did not match number of bytes read; the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor of the client library.
Error: 17836, Severity: 20, State: 14. I am getting this error 5 times at the same time almost and want to know the reason for its occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the solution [here](http://blogs.lostincreativity.com/sqldba/length-specified-in-network-packet-payload-did-not-match-number-of-bytes-read-the-connection-has-been-closed-please-contact-the-vendor-of-the-client-library-client-xx-xx-xx-xx/):

> Since the SQL Server has Event ID 17836 logged, the SQL port is open.
>   It is more like authentication issue. Based on this articles
>   (Configuration for querying SQL database remotely –
>   http://www.howtonetworking.com/others/testsqlconnect2.htm ), we may
>   have 3 fixes:
>
> - creating SQL login ID (recommended)
> - join the computer to the domain
> - allow anonymous connections to SQL Server 2000 or to SQL Server 2005    (don’t recommend)

And this [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04446c40-0623-4528-bbbd-f05f9578e5a0/error-17836-severity-20-state-1?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

> Perform a nslookup of the CLIENT IP Address that is listed in the
>   error message and find out what computer it is that is connecting. 
>   Then you need to check that machine and determine what specifically is
>   connecting to the SQL Server.  You might get more infromation from
>   doing a SQL Trace for the Errors and Warnings Event Class and have the
>   ClientProcessID column in the trace data.  When the error spikes, you
>   might get the PID for the process that is connecting from that
>   10.26.32.96 machine, and then you can find that process in Task Manager on that machine by adding the PID to the data displayed (View
>   -> Select Columns).

Comment: Link 1 is dead..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, these events coincided with me doing telnet connectivity tests to our SQL Servers. We would see one entry in the Windows Event Log for each instance we successfully did a telnet to.

Answer (score 0):

**2024 update:**

This issue occurs due to **Trust Server Certificate** which should be enabled to connect SQL Server.

I was using mssql image to run on docker and tried to connect using DBeaver to the mssql container. But, it was showing this error. So, after seeing microsoft docs, I tried to connect using Azure data studio and it connected with the same settings I used in DBeaver. But, there was a catch, it asked for enabling trust certificate which was news to me.

So, I saw an option for trust server certificate while connecting through DBeaver and it worked.

Just another bonus point(for DBeaver only):
Once you get connected to the sql server, it will only show the db that you mentioned while connecting to the server. To see all the DBs, you can right click on connection --> Connection view --> Advanced

This will show all the DBs in the server.